# Floor function as derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a function f such that $f'(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

I was thinking no, since if you draw it out and look at the integral, it should be an imaginary number, right?

But how do I explain it?

Comment: No. You could appeal to [Darboux's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29).

Comment: I was actually thinking about it, also. Can i use this as a counter example? 
consider $1/2\in[0,4]$, by Darboux, then there exists $x\in(0,4)$ such that $f'(x)=1/2$

Comment: Yes, that would show that no such $f$ exists as in your post (it's not really a counterexample, though; rather, part of a proof that there is no such $f$ via contradiction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, no if you wish for $f$ to be differentiable (as pointed out by David Mitra, [Darboux's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29) can be used to formalize this). However, you could consider [weak derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative). Then $f$ could be a picewise linear function, the step of which is $\lfloor x \rfloor$, e.g. (there are many because of the integration constant):

$\hspace{40pt}$[image]

Be aware that this is not *regular* antiderivative, on the other hand it's quite a common occurence in practical applications. The shape is in fact almost the same as the example of @icurays1, still it might be just more intuitive to make it continous. I hope I didn't confused you ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The integral certainly won't be an imaginary number, but you'll have an issue at the integers because the floor function has a jump discontinuity there, which will manifest itself as a "kink" in the integral. The function below will have $f^\prime=\lfloor x\rfloor$ at all noninteger points:

$$
f(x)=nx,\; x\in [n,n+1)\quad n\in\Bbb{Z}
$$

However, this function is not differentiable if $x=k$ where $k\in\Bbb{Z}$.  As suggested by the comment, it can be shown that in fact *no* such function can exist that has $f^\prime(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ for *all* $x$.