# Proving $y=\lfloor x\rfloor$ doesn't have a primitive function

Tags: calculus, integration

> Prove that $y=\lfloor x\rfloor$ doesn't have a primitive function.

I have the proof from a book here but I don't understand it:

> Suppose that there is $F(x)$ such that $F'(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$. We
>   have that $y=\lfloor x\rfloor$ has a jump discontinuity (or type 1)
>   but $F'(x)$ has only an essential discontinuity (or type 2), a
>   contradiction.

I don't understand, why does $F'(x)$ has an essential discontinuity?

Comment: The word is a primitive or an antiderivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is silently appealing to [Darboux’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29):

> If $I$ is an open interval, and $f:I\to\Bbb R$ is a differentiable function, then $f'$ has the intermediate value property. That is, if $a,b\in I$, $a<b$, and $y$ is between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$, then there is an $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f'(x)=y$.

This means that a derivative cannot have a jump discontinuity and therefore cannot be the floor function. In particular, suppose that $F'(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$, and take $I$ to be the interval $(-1,2)$. Then $0,1\in I$, and

$$F'(0)=\lfloor 0\rfloor=0<\frac12<1=\lfloor 1\rfloor=F'(1)\;,$$

but there is no $x\in[0,1]$ such that $F'(x)=\frac12$, contradicting Darboux’s theorem.

Answer (score -1):

A fairly 'wild' answer would be for $x>0$:
$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \delta(x-n)$$

Comment: Um I don't understand... I don't know how to derive a series either but I suppose the derivative is the floor function here, then that still doesn't explain why does the derivative has an essential discontinuity.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250906/floor-function-as-derivative

Comment: Well, that's "primitive" in a sense but not a *function*.